# Why does only (not set) show e-commerce data by country in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Why can't we see e-commerce data by country?

[screenshot of GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdDN8.png)

Using the explore function to create a table of the different countries, their add to cart and revenue

Only the (not set) shows e-commerce data...

The same with device category, only "Desktop" category shows e-commerce data

Comment: Is this a programming-related problem?

Comment: not sure, how do we find out?

Comment: Your question must explicitly be a programming-related question. You need to make that clear in what you ask. Just because there may be a programmatic answer it doesn't mean that the question is programming-related.